# Connecting to MSSQL server with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sql-server, azure, sequelize.js

Using the following tedious code, I can successfully connect to an Azure SQL Server.

```
const Connection = require('tedious').Connection;

const connection = new Connection({
    userName: '[USER]',
    password: '[PASSWORD]',
    server: '[HOSTNAME]',
    options: {encrypt: true}
});

connection.on('connect', (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error connecting', err);
    } else {
        console.log('connection successful');
    }
});
```

However, using what should be the equivalent Sequelize code, I get a connection timeout error.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('[DBNAME]', '[USER]', '[PASSWORD]', {
    dialect: 'mssql',
    host: '[HOSTNAME]',
    dialectOptions: {
        encrypt: true
    }
});

sequelize.authenticate().then((err) => {
    console.log('Connection successful', err);
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log('Unable to connect to database', err);
});
```

Any thoughts?

Using: sequelize 3.29.0, tedious 1.14.0, SQL Server v12

Answer (score 18):

I was getting below error

`SequelizeConnectionError: Server requires encryption, set 'encrypt' config option to true.`

I tried it out with Azure SQL Database and below way is working for me.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('DB Name', 'Username', 'Password', {
    host: 'Host',
    dialect: 'mssql',
    dialectOptions: {
        options: {
            encrypt: true,
        }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're trying it out with Azure SQL Database, you might also want to specify a longer request timeout value:

```
[...]
dialectOptions: {
    requestTimeout: 30000 // timeout = 30 seconds
}
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your Sequelize code and it works fine. So you might need to add **Client IP address** to allow access to Azure SQL Server. To do this, go to the [Azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com), click on **All Resources**, select your SQL server, click on **Firewall** in the **SETTINGS** menu.

[image]

Your client address is conveniently included in the list, so you can just click on **Add client IP** followed by **Save**. When you run your code now, it should connect.

Comment: My client IP is already added to the firewall whitelist, which is how the Tedious code is connecting directly. My confusing is coming from why the Tedious code is connecting properly but the Sequelize code isn't when Sequelize is just using Tedious to connect.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using sql server management studio then simply replace `dialect:'mysql'` with `dialect:'mssql'`:

```
 const sequelize = new Sequelize('DB Name', 'Username', 'Password', {
    host: 'Host',
    dialect: 'mssql',
    dialectOptions: {
        options: {
            encrypt: true,
        }
    }
  });
```